# Is there a way to have only one URL per product in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

It looks like a product may have many different URLs in Shopify.  For example, a product that is part of two collections (say, "Televisions" and "LCD TVs") will have two different URLs, depending on how the user arrives at it.  This poses problems for SEO, since search engines will penalize you for having duplicate content on your site.  It also makes it harder to advertise products and track results, since you'd have to combine stats from all URLs of that product.  Is there a way around this?  Can we "force" products to have only one official URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a canonical URL, you will not have this problem. By using that simple Liquid construct:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" />
```

Your product will always be indexed with one URL and no silly penalties.